# Create an event. This event should occur when a certain string has changed

Tags: vb.net, event-handling

I go far back to make clear the context. First, I noticed today that if there are several controls on the form, you cannot use the arrow keys because the controls (e.g. ComboBox, textbox) take the cursor and focus. Therefore, I created a second form ("SteuerForm" (Steering Form)). There are no controls on this. I also found out that you can only get the arrow keys with the `KeyDown` event. The `KeyDown` event is disadvantageous when it comes to certain characters: "Shiftkey" and "Oem7" are output instead of the specific letter (e.g. `Ä`). That's why I actually wanted to use `KeyPress`. Eventually, I wrote a class ("Class_Key"). It contains a `list(Of string)` with certain key names that I must have.

Now I want the `Private Sub new_message()` in Form1 to be called when the string `letzte_Taste` (`last_key`) changes.

**Edit:** I want some event in the Class_Key Class to fire a method (new_message) in the main form. How can I do that? The event is supposed to be fired when the string letzte_Taste changes from one (eg `"Up"`) to another (eg `"Down"`).

[image: 3 classes, 2 forms]

**SteuerForm.vb**

```
Public NotInheritable Class SteuerForm
    Private Sub SteuerForm_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyPress
        If Class_Key.Tasten.Contains(e.KeyChar.ToString) Then
            Class_Key.letzte_Taste = e.KeyChar.ToString
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub SteuerForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.KeyPreview = True
        Me.Location = New Point(500, 0)
    End Sub

    Private Sub SteuerForm_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyDown
        If Class_Key.Tasten.Contains(e.KeyCode.ToString) Then
            Class_Key.letzte_Taste = e.KeyCode.ToString
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

**Class_Key.vb**

```
Public NotInheritable Class Class_Key
    Public Shared Tasten As New List(Of String) From {
        "Up",
        "Down",
        "Left",
        "Right",
        "Return",
        "Back",
        "Space",
        "Add",
        "Subtract",
        "a"} 'and another alphabetic characters... (I shortened this...)

    Public Shared letzte_Taste As String = ""
End Class
```

Comment: It's not really too clear what you're asking here. You want some event in the Class_Key Class to fire a method in the main form?  Have you declared an instance of Class_Key in your main form, if so is it WithEvents?  Or is your issue which event should you be capturing?

Comment: @Hursey Hi, "You want some event in the Class_Key Class to fire a method in the main form?" Yes.

Comment: "Have you declared an instance of Class_Key in your main form?" No, should I?

Comment: Have a read over this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/events/

Comment: Have a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged?view=net-5.0 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged?view=net-5.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it! This is my solution.

```
Public NotInheritable Class Class_Key
    Public Shared Tasten As New List(Of String) From {
        "Up",
        "Down",
        "Left",
        "Right",
        "Return",
        "Back",
        "Space",
        "Add",
        "Subtract",
        "a"}

    Public Shared Property letzte_Taste As String = ""
    Public Shared Property vorletzte_Taste As String = ""
    Public Shared Event AnEvent()
    Public Shared Zaehler As UInt16 = 0
    Public Shared Sub Pruefung()
        If Not letzte_Taste = vorletzte_Taste Then
            RaiseEvent AnEvent()
            Zaehler += Convert.ToUInt16(1)
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

```
Public NotInheritable Class SteuerForm
    Private Sub SteuerForm_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyPress
        If Class_Key.Tasten.Contains(e.KeyChar.ToString) Then
            Class_Key.letzte_Taste = e.KeyChar.ToString
        End If
        Class_Key.Pruefung()
        Class_Key.vorletzte_Taste = Class_Key.letzte_Taste
    End Sub

    Private Sub SteuerForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.KeyPreview = True
        Me.Location = New Point(500, 0)
    End Sub

    Private Sub SteuerForm_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyDown
        If Class_Key.Tasten.Contains(e.KeyCode.ToString) Then
            Class_Key.letzte_Taste = e.KeyCode.ToString
        End If
        Class_Key.Pruefung()
        Class_Key.vorletzte_Taste = Class_Key.letzte_Taste
    End Sub
End Class
```

**in Form1_Load**

```
AddHandler Class_Key.AnEvent, AddressOf neue_Nachricht
```

**in Form1**

```
Private Sub neue_Nachricht()
    Debug.WriteLine($"caught event. Nr. {Class_Key.Zaehler}")
End Sub
```